# dashboard become white when I add mailup in magento 1.7.1

Tags: php

[image]

When I add mailup in magento, I receive the following error message on the dashboard :

> Class 'MailUp_MailUpSync_Helper_Data' not found

Comment: Blank means you have any php error and you log is not enable. Enable your log you will able to debug the issue

Comment: log is enable. I am going to post an image before you see the problem very well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Do not share a screenshot but put directly your log. Please edit your post!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in `app/code/local/MailUp/MailUpSync/Helper/` or `app/code/community/MailUp/MailUpSync/Helper/` and see if the Data.php class file is there?

The extension needs that class and seems to be the reported error.

If it's not there, go through the extension and place all the files in their correct folders again.

Comment: Thank PhilS, I saw the Data.php fil in app/code/local/MailUp/MailUpSync/Helper/. I move the folder MialUp to app/code/community/, but the probleme is not always resolved. I don't know how to do.